# Find and Modify txt File in C++

Tags: c++, file, search, replace

I want to find a specific `id` from file and modify content.
Here is originol code which I want.

```
// test.txt

id_1
arfan
haider

id_2
saleem
haider

id_3
someone
otherone
```

C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namesapce std;

int main(){
     istream readFile("test.txt");
     string readout;
     string search;
     string Fname;
     string Lname;

     cout<<"Enter id which you want Modify";
     cin>>search;

     while(getline(readFile,readout)){
        if(readout == search){
           /*
                id remain same (does not change)
                But First name and Last name replace with
                user Fname and Lname
           */
            cout<<"Enter new First name";
                 cin>>Fname;
            cout<<"Enter Last name";
                 cin>>Lname;  
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose:
A user search id *id_2*. After that user enter First name and Last name *Shafiq* and *Ahmed*.
After runing this code the `test.txt` File must modify the record like that:

```
...............
...............

id_2
Shafiq
Ahmad

.................
.................
```

Only `id_2` record change remaing file will be same.
**UPDATE:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ofstream outFile("temp.txt");
ifstream readFile("test.txt");

string readLine;
string search;
string firstName;
string lastName;

cout<<"Enter The Id :: ";
cin>>search;

while(getline(readFile,readLine))
{
    if(readLine == search)
    {
        outFile<<readLine;
        outFile<<endl;

        cout<<"Enter New First Name :: ";
        cin>>firstName;
        cout<<"Enter New Last Name :: ";
        cin>>lastName;

        outFile<<firstName<<endl;
        outFile<<lastName<<endl;
    }else{
        outFile<<readLine<<endl;
    }
}
}
```

It also contain pervious First Name and Last Name in `temp.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

After finding the specific id and writing the new first name and last name, you need to skip the following two lines. This code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void skipLines(ifstream& stream, int nLines)
{
    string dummyLine;
    for(int i = 0; i < nLines; ++i)
        getline(stream, dummyLine);
}

int main()
{
    ofstream outFile("temp.txt");
    ifstream readFile("test.txt");

    string readLine;
    string search;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;

    cout<<"Enter The Id :: ";
    cin>>search;

    while(getline(readFile,readLine))
    {
        if(readLine == search)
        {
            outFile<<readLine;
            outFile<<endl;

            cout<<"Enter New First Name :: ";
            cin>>firstName;
            cout<<"Enter New Last Name :: ";
            cin>>lastName;

            outFile<<firstName<<endl;
            outFile<<lastName<<endl;
            skipLines(readFile, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            outFile<<readLine<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```